# Slow start for headless chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, google-chrome-headless

My test runs slow when i use "--headless" argument together with "--ignore-certificate-errors". But i need to use "--ignore-certificate-errors" because of SSL errors.
I am using ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30.

---

Here is my setup.

```
@BeforeSuite
public static void setup()  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080","--ignore-certificate-errors");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT,CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT,CaptureType.REQUEST_HEADERS);
    proxy.newHar("first");
    driver.get("https://here is hiden url");
    har = proxy.getHar();
}
```

---

And pom dependencies if necessary

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-proxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

---

10 seconds without --headless

30 seconds with --headless

Is there any way to fix this problem?